# How to display real time data on analog scale if maximum send rate is 50ms

Tags: microcontroller, current, programming, display, real-time

I have nextion display on witch is positioned analog scale. It needs to present Amps from device which mcu monitoring. Problem is that current can grow by several tens of amperes in just several milliseconds but refresh command to display can be performed every 50ms. How to properly display data to have smooth move of arrow? Is there some formula or technique to do that? [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the most common methods is **moving average**.

Suppose your samples are every 5 ms and your updates are every 50 ms.  Suppose you want an average over the last 500 ms.  The simplest method is that every 50 ms you show the average of the last 100 samples.  Choosing the numbers depends on what your data is like and what you want to show.

A common variant which is more responsive to the most recent input is the **decaying average**.

Consider also the method you see on level meters on mixing desks: the main bar shows the current decaying average; also, the most recent peak is shown as a single pixel on.

You'll find a great deal of variants.  A good place to start is Wikipedi'a [Moving Average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) page.

As this is actually a complex part of the human-machine interface, you'll find there's an incredible literature on the subject, and the requirements for level meters (on mixing desks) is quite different from the requirements of speedometers and fuel-tank level meters in cars.  In the level meter, you might want "ballistics", which simulate the effect of the input on a meter needle with momentum.  The fuel level meter has special requirements near zero, and tricky sensors (which tend to me inaccurate when tilted.)

Have a look at these, for example:

- Wikipedia [Peak Programme Meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_programme_meter)
- How engineers think about it [AES Journal](https://www.digido.com/portfolio-item/level-practices-part-2/) article by Bob Katz. ("How To Make Better Recordings in the 21st Century – An Integrated Approach to Metering, Monitoring, and Leveling Practices.")

Answer (score 6):

How to choose which current to display: it depends on your application :

- you want the simplest solution: take a measurement every 50 ms and display it
- you mostly care about the maximum current (for example to monitor overload) : take many measurements during each 50 ms period, and display the maximum
- you mostly care about the average current (for example, you care about discharging a battery): take many measurements during each 50 ms period, and display the average
- you want precise information: take many measurements during each 50 ms period, and compute the minimum, average and maximum, and display 3 arrows (maybe a thick one for average, and 2 thin ones for min/max), or a single wide one going from min to max (you no longer see the average)

If you don't like the arrow moving too fast, you can in addition use a digital low pass filter (i.e. do an averaging with the previously displayed values): it will move smoother, but you will add some lag, and you will hide short peaks. Lets call m_t the measurement at time t, and d_t the displayed value at time t. There are several solutions:

- average over a time windows : d_t = ( m_{t-n+1} + m_{t-n+2} + ... + m_{t-1} + m_{t} )/n. This is the simplest solution.
- weighted moving average : d_t = ( a_{t-n+1}*m_{t-n+1} + a_{t-n+2}*m_{t-n+2} + ... + a_{t-1}*m_{t-1} + a_{t}*m_{t} )/ (a_{t-n+1} + a_{t-n+2} + ... + a_{t-1} + a_{t} ). This allows you to decrease the weight of older values. You can for example use a_{t-i} = 2^(-i).
- digital low pass filter: d_0=m_0, then d_t= x*d_{t-1} + (1-x)*m_{t}, with 0<x<1 : the higher x, the more you take into account old measurements. NB: even very old measurements are still taken into account, but with very small weight (measurement m_{t-i} has weight (1-x)*x^(i-1)).

Answer (score 2):

The way you have worded your question means you have not yet thought through your requirements.

If you want to display real time data, then you display the latest data as soon as you can.

As you can only update the display every 50 ms, this means you compact the current measurements of the previous 50 ms into a single value (maybe average, maybe peak) and throw it at the display.

> How to properly display data to have smooth move of arrow?

Ah, smooth, what does that mean? Emulate a moving needle meter? Display some decaying average.

Yes, you can do either of those with a little digital filtering. Just define a filter type, and a time constant or two, and use a digital filter on your stream of current readings, and display its output every 50 ms.

Choose a filter type based on how you expect the user is going to use the indication. For instance, VU meters have very different, and specific, dynamics to other types of meters, based on the needs of the audio mixer fraternity.

You can even create non-linear filters, such as used in weighing machines, if that's the behaviour you want. Generally they use short and long time constant low pass filters, displaying the long time constant output for low noise, switching briefly to the short filter output when they differ by more than a threshold, which suggests a step change to the input has occurred, so leading to a faster real time response.

Once you have a basic system, modifying filter type and time constants based on your users' feedback is called 'tuning'. This is an iterative process, and may never terminate!